# how do I get apache http client 4.0.1 (org.apache.httpcomponents) to redirect automatically to a get after a post?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, client

According to the documentation, the apache http client is supposed to automatically redirect. I am submitting a post to a server, and it has a redirect. Unfortunately, the response handler is giving back an empty string. It just isn't following the redirect and giving me that content directly. Is there an easy way to get the client to follow redirects?

Answer (score 1):

You could be seeing the result of a particularly ugly area of the [RFC-2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).  The `Location` header is used to redirect a client depending on the exact status code.  The interesting ones are 201, 301, 302, and 303.  The *correct* handling depends heavily on which one you are receiving.  My guess is that you should be receiving a `303 See Other` and you are receiving a different code *and* your client is following the various HTTP specifications.

I don't know the behavior of Apache's HTTP client, but I do know that many implementations of server and client get this behavior wrong.  Here are the relevant chunks of RFC-2616.  I apologize for this being a rather long-winded answer.

> **10.2.2. 201 Created**

The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created. The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for the resource given by a Location header field. The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. The origin server MUST create the resource before returning the 201 status code. If the action cannot be carried out immediately, the server SHOULD respond with 202 (Accepted) response instead.

> **10.3.2. 301 Moved Permanently**
>
> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs.  Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The new permanent URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
>
> *If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.*
>
> Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will erroneously change it into a GET request.
>
> **10.3.3. 302 Found**
>
> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.  This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.
>
> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
>
> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.
>
> *Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed to change the method on the redirected request. However, most existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303 response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which kind of reaction is expected of the client.*
>
> **10.3.4 303 See Other**
>
> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second (redirected) request might be cacheable.
>
> The different URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
>
> Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303 status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the 302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react to a 302 response as described here for 303.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it with apache HttpComponents 4.3.5, You have to specify your redirect strategy to follow redirects.

Here is how I did it.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .build();
```